# writing data from a python list to csv row-wise

Tags: python, csv

Using python, i am writing data from a list to a .csv file, row-wise.

Code:

```
writer=csv.writer(open(filepath,'wb'))
header=['type','id','numberOfUpdates','isPingEnabled','lastUpdated']
length_list=len(header)
i=0

while i!=length_list :
    data=header[i]
    print data
    i=i+1
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Result: Data is being written to csv file but each letter is printed in each column.

For example: type is written as 't' in one column, 'y' in next column and so on.
I need the whole word in one column. Can some one point out what change can i make?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this question deserves a downvote. It is a clearly written question. The only fault the OP made was probably not fully understanding the documentation of the csv module.

Comment: +1 IMHO there is nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Change `writer.writerow(data)` to `writer.writerow([data])`.

`.writerow` takes an iterable and uses each element of that iterable for each column. If you use a list with only one element it will be placed in a single column.

You should also restructure your loop:

```
for word in header:
    writer.writerow([word])
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
for item in RESULTS:
     wr.writerow([item,])
```